# Is there a command can do the reverse of what the paste command does?

Tags: text-processing, paste

The `paste` command can merge multiple lines into one. For example, if I have a file `test.txt` and it contains:

#### original text

```
a
aa
aaa
b
bb
bbb
c
cc
ccc
```

I can use the command `paste -s -d '\t\t\n' test.txt` to get:

#### processed result

```
a   aa  aaa
b   bb  bbb
c   cc  ccc
```

I want to know if there is a reverse command that can do the reverse of paste. For example, If I have "processed result", how can I get "original text"?

Comment: Something like: `python -c 'import sys;for line in sys.stdin:print(*line.split(), sep="\n")'` ?   If you want to split a line *only* on tabs and not on any whitespace sequence replace  `.split()` with `.split("\t")`.

Comment: The reverse of `paste` is `cut`, but only when `paste` is used to merge multiple files (so that each column comes from a different file). For the line-merging use that your question is about, `cut` cannot reverse it.

Answer (score 10):

There's no standard command.

You must do it your self, and depends on your input.

In this case:

```
tr '\t' '\n' <pasted_file.txt
```

will give you the original one.

Note that it assumes `\t` doesn't appear in your original file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this sed command on your processed result

```
sed -e 'y/\t/\n/' processedresult.txt
```

Comment: That won't work with most `sed` implementations. POSIXly, the behaviour is undefined if the backslash is followed by anything but `/`, backslash or `n`. `tr '\t' '\n'` would be more to the point and more portable.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You could just use a literal tab.

Comment: I have only a single system on which to test answers I suggest. I try to ensure all answers I provide work on "my" implementation (Debian i686). While it may not be as portable as tr, my answer does work on my system. Thank you for your comments and suggestion .

Comment: You can always check the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). If it's standard, it should be fairly portable. Debian is a GNU system, GNU utilities have a lot of extensions over the standard so something working on Debian is not always a good indication of whether it's going to work on other Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: @Stéphane, I think it's a little excessive to require people to consult the POSIX specification for every answer-- it will discourage answers rather than make them better. But if you know you're in this situation, rcjohnson, it won't hurt to add a disclaimer like "Works with GNU sed, at least; YMMV". Then the reader is warned (and maybe others will confirm it works).

Comment: @alexis, I agree with you. I meant that if one care about writing portable answers, he can always check the POSIX spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace character by sed or character by tr:

```
sed -e 's/< old string >/< new string >/g' input-file > output-file
```

s for replace, and g for replacing each occurrence of the < old string > in one line. Without g, replacement will be occurred only once per line.

```
tr '< old char >' '< new char >' < input-file > output-file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk version:

```
awk -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1; print}' input-file > output-file
```